# The Delta Method asymptotic distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, central-limit-theorem

I've managed to get through a) and b) but now I'm stumped with this delta method and cramer theorem stuff:

let X be Gamma random variable with parameter $\alpha$=4 and $\lambda$=$\theta$:

a)Find the Fisher Information

b)Determine the MLE of $\theta$ an a sample from Gamma

c)Use the delta method to derive the asymptotic distribution from Gamma (at rate $\sqrt n$ or the MLE $\theta$)

d)Use Cramers's theorem to derive the asymptotic distribution at rate $\sqrt n$ or the MLE $\theta$)

my answer so far are:

a) $\alpha/\lambda^2$

b) $\hat \lambda = \alpha / \bar x$

I don't really understand the delta method formula and how to use in with the MLE that I derived.

$\sqrt{n}(X_n - \mu) \Rightarrow_n^\infty X \sim N(o,\sigma^2)$

some pointers on that would be really helpfully.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer to b is wrong, the $n$ shouldn't be there. For c: By the Central Limit Theorem and some assumptions you can deduce a distribution for $\bar{x}$. Then use the delta method on $\bar{x}$ with the function $g(y) = 4/y$.

Comment: what happens to the n? Does it just go to 1?

Comment: You should get $\hat\lambda = 4n/\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i$. Then by dividing in the numerator and denominator by $n$ you get $4/\bar{x}$.

Comment: Or isn't $\bar{x}$ the population average in your notation?

Comment: yeah it is I had $\lambda = n\alpha / \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ I guess I didn't deal with the n properly